# The script won't affect single object only on multiple

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

I don't understand why I get an error when I apply this script on a single object. On multiple objects it works perfectly.

The second thing is, before I run the script I need to manually convert some object in the scene to `ePoly`, otherwise the 'quadrify' line in the script won't work at all... (It looks like a bug but it happened on the previous version also, I'm using Max 2017).

```
try (destroydialog ConvertToEPoly) catch()

rollout ConvertToEPoly "Edit Poly and Quadrify v3.0"

    (
        label lab1 "-- Convet to ePoly and Quadrify --" 
        button b1 "Convert" pos:[35,27] height: 60 width: 150 
        progressbar Progress "Progrres" height: 25 color: orange pos: [13,95]
        on b1 pressed do 

        (

                    MyArray = selection as array
                    for i in 1 to selection.count do
                        (
                            convertToPoly $[i]
                            select $[i]
                            PolyToolsModeling.Quadrify true false
                            Progress.value = (100.0*i/MyArray.count) 
                            if Progress.value>99 do (Progress.value=0)
                            completeRedraw()
                            select MyArray

                        )

        )


    )

createdialog ConvertToEPoly height: 130 width: 220
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found a solution to this yet, but I figured I'd chime in seeing as there isn't an answer here yet.

When you run this on a single object, '$' isn't being treated as an array, but as a single object. This means that rather than accessing the object itself, you're accessing a property of the object (in this case, the error is pointing to 'SubAnim:Visibility').

I tinkered around with your code and came up with a solution that works for both single and multi selection:

```
try (destroydialog ConvertToEPoly) catch()

rollout ConvertToEPoly "Edit Poly and Quadrify v3.0"

    (
        label lab1 "-- Convet to ePoly and Quadrify --" 
        button b1 "Convert" pos:[35,27] height: 60 width: 150 
        progressbar Progress "Progrres" height: 25 color: orange pos: [13,95]
        on b1 pressed do 

        (           
            MyArray = selection as array
            count = 1
            for obj in MyArray do
                (                           
                    convertToPoly obj
                    select obj
                    PolyToolsModeling.Quadrify true false
                    Progress.value = (100.0*count/MyArray.count)                            
                    completeRedraw()
                    count = count + 1
                )
            Progress.value = 0
            select MyArray
        )
    )

createdialog ConvertToEPoly height: 130 width: 220
```

This works because your entire selection is being treated as an array, even if you only have one thing selected (hence the `for obj in MyArray do` in line 12).

Cheers!